Unable to see my log messages below than Warning on Azure Monitor
I created an Azure Static Web App. I can see the requests of my API functions being executed in application insights (Monitor). But I can't see the log messages below than Warning. In the Azure Function, I'm logging messages as shown below:
        _logger.LogTrace($">>> Log Trace");
        _logger.LogDebug($">>> Log Debug");
        _logger.LogInformation($">>> Log Information");
        _logger.LogWarning($">>> Log Warning");
        _logger.LogError($">>> Log Error");
        _logger.LogCritical($">>> Log Critical");

        Console.WriteLine($">>> Console WriteLine");

As you can see below it is missing Trace Debug Information logging messages.

Below is my .csproj file.
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
    <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net8.0</TargetFramework>
    <AzureFunctionsVersion>v4</AzureFunctionsVersion>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <ItemGroup>
    <FrameworkReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker" Version="1.20.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.Http" Version="3.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.Http.AspNetCore" Version="1.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Sdk" Version="1.16.4" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WorkerService" Version="2.21.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.ApplicationInsights" Version="1.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="8.0.4" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite" Version="8.0.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" Version="8.0.3">
        <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
        <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json" Version="13.0.3" />
    </ItemGroup>
    <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\SoutienScolaireV2.Shared\SoutienScolaireV2.Shared.csproj" />
    </ItemGroup>
    <ItemGroup>
    <None Update="Data\database.db">
        <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Update="host.json">
        <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Update="local.settings.json">
        <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
        <CopyToPublishDirectory>Never</CopyToPublishDirectory>
    </None>
    </ItemGroup>
    <ItemGroup>
    <Using Include="System.Threading.ExecutionContext" Alias="ExecutionContext" />
    </ItemGroup>
    <ItemGroup>
    <Folder Include="Data\" />
    </ItemGroup>
</Project>

Below is my host.json file.
{
  "version": "2.0",
  "logging": {
    "applicationInsights": {
      "logLevel": {
        "default": "Information",
        "Function": "Information"
      },
      "samplingSettings": {
        "isEnabled": true,
        "excludedTypes": "Request",
        "logLevel": {
          "default": "Trace"
        }
      },
      "enableLiveMetricsFilters": true
    },
    "logLevel": {
      "default": "Information",
      "Function": "Information"
    }
  }
}

What is missing in order to see all of my logging messages ?

What is the version of your app?Can you please share your .csproj file?

Also please share your host.jsob code in text format.

@Harshitha I updated my question with the requested info.

So the issue is in azure function hosted in static we app you are unable to log information and trace ?

@Harshitha Indeed. As you can see in my question, I log different kind of messages but Trace and Information messages are never showed in Monitor on my Azure portal.

Try with this Configuration in host.json file.

The link you suggested above is useful when no logs are getting written to Application Insights. This is not the case for me. Only Trace, Debug and Information log messages are missing.

Ok..Will try from my end.

Have you tried the configuration which I have shared ?

@Harshitha yes with same result as before.

Can you please share your code repo?

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

I have tried with your code and done changes in Program.cs file.
 services.Configure<LoggerFilterOptions>(options =>
 {
     LoggerFilterRule logfilter = options.Rules.FirstOrDefault(rule => rule.ProviderName
         == "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ApplicationInsights.ApplicationInsightsLoggerProvider");

     if (logfilter is not null)
     {
         options.Rules.Remove(logfilter);
     }
 });


Now I am able to see the Log Information traces along with other severity levels.

My Program.cs file:
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

var host = new HostBuilder()
    .ConfigureFunctionsWebApplication()
    .ConfigureServices(services =>
    {
        services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetryWorkerService();
        services.ConfigureFunctionsApplicationInsights();
        services.Configure<LoggerFilterOptions>(options =>
        {
            LoggerFilterRule logfilter = options.Rules.FirstOrDefault(rule => rule.ProviderName
                == "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ApplicationInsights.ApplicationInsightsLoggerProvider");

            if (logfilter is not null)
            {
                options.Rules.Remove(logfilter);
            }
        });
    })    
    .Build();
host.Run();


And I am able to log all the traces with my default code with the below configuration as well.

My host.json file:
{
  "version": "2.0",
  "logging": {
    "applicationInsights": {
      "samplingSettings": {
        "isEnabled": true,
        "excludedTypes": "Request"
      }
    },
    "logLevel": {
      "default": "Information"
    }
  }
}


When we create Function App,Initially Application Insights is configured for local.
Disconnect it and change it to Azure Application Insights.


Refer this SOthread to configure it.
My .csproj file:
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
  <TargetFramework>net8.0</TargetFramework>
  <AzureFunctionsVersion>v4</AzureFunctionsVersion>
  <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
  <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
  <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
  <ApplicationInsightsResourceId>/subscriptions/****/resourceGroups/****/providers/microsoft.insights/components/AppInsights</ApplicationInsightsResourceId>
  <UserSecretsId>****</UserSecretsId>
</PropertyGroup>
 <ItemGroup>
   <FrameworkReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" />
   <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker" Version="1.20.1" />
   <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.Http" Version="3.1.0" />
   <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.Http.AspNetCore" Version="1.2.0" />
   <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Sdk" Version="1.16.4" />
   <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WorkerService" Version="2.21.0" />
   <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.ApplicationInsights" Version="1.1.0" />
   <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.UserSecrets" Version="8.0.0" />
 </ItemGroup>
    -------
    -------          
</Project>

Transaction Search:

Logs:

Live Metrics:

